# not able to connect cluster to opscenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, opscenter

hyy folks,
i have setup cassandra gui using this doc https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.8/install/opscInstallRHEL.html

but as soon as i hit the url it will open this page

[image: error]
here i chosen manage existing clsuter and go to next page
there it is shown like this
[image: iamge]
there i paste my private ip
[image]

but as soon i hit next it showing this error
[image: error]

how can i add my cluster in opscenter

`sudo service opscenterd status`
it is showing in Running state

i entered username and password then it is showing this
[image]

Comment: Have you installed Apache Cassandra on your cluster nodes? OpsCenter requires DataStax Enterprise (DSE), which is a different product and is a fork of Cassandra.

Comment: yes apigee cassandra is installed in my nodes

Answer (score 2):

OpsCenter only works with [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise).

You cannot use OpsCenter to connect to:

- open-source Apache Cassandra,
- other distributions which are forks of Cassandra, or
- versions from cloud vendors which run a CQL API engine to make the database "look and feel" like Cassandra.

Cheers!